# QT - embedding translations works on Windows, not on Linux

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, translation

In the SQLiteStudio I started using `CONFIG += lrelease embed_translations` for automatically embedding all translations into the app's resources. I did so by declaring:

```
CONFIG  += lrelease embed_translations
QM_FILES_RESOURCE_PREFIX = /msg/translations
TRANSLATIONS += $$files(translations/*.ts)
```

This is done for all modules (in their `pro` files). Modules are compiled into shared libraries (such as `coreSQLiteStudio`, `guiSQLiteStudio` and then there is a executable module `sqlitestudio`, which is the application to run and it's dynamically linked to others, so it looks like:

```
sqlitestudio                    <- executable (contains *.qm files)
  `- guiSQLiteStudio.so                       (contains *.qm files)
       `- coreSQLiteStudio.so                 (contains *.qm files)
```

Then in runtime I'm using translation files with Qt's resources system (by call to `QTranslator::load()` with `:/msg/translations/coreSQLiteStudio_pl_PL.qm`, `:/msg/translations/sqlitestudio_pl_PL.qm`, etc).

This works well under Windows, but - for some reason - not under Linux. The problem is that under Linux only files from `sqlitestudio` module (i.e. `sqlitestudio_pl_PL.qm`) are visible under the `:/msg/translations` prefix, while under Windows also other module translations (i.e. `coreSQLiteStudio_pl_PL.qm`, `guiSQLiteStudio_pl_PL.qm`) are visible under the same prefix.

I've debugged `TRANSLATIONS += $$files(translations/*.ts)` and it is resolved properly for all modules (under Linux too). Then I have debugged runtime contents of `:/msg/translations` and confirmed that only `sqlitestudio` qm files are visible under Linux, while under Windows all qm files (from all modules) are visible.

What could be causing this weird behavior?

(For wider code context you may refer to [SQLiteStudio's code base](https://github.com/pawelsalawa/sqlitestudio) - it's open source and available at GitHub)

**EDIT - Further analysis:**

A qrc file is generated properly by Qt, I can see it and it has expected contents. I also see the `rcc` to compile it to the cpp file and `make` to compile it to the object file, then I see the object file linked into the final shared library. I can see all these intermediate files in the build directory.

It seems that the problem is in runtime. I've listed all resources visible using function:

```
void printResources(const QString& path, int indent)
{
    QDir d;
    d.setPath(path);
    for (QString& f : d.entryList(QStringList({"*"})))
    {
        qDebug() << QString(" ").repeated(indent) << f;
        if (!f.contains(".")) {
            printResources(path + "/" + f, indent + 4);
        }
    }
}
```

and then calling `printResources(":/", 0);`, which printed various resources, but it DID NOT contain QM files from the shared library resources, while it does contain QM files from the executable resources. It also has all resources that were explicitly added to another resources file in the shared library (some static resources, not auto generated qm files).

Why does Qt have problems accessing QM auto-generated resources from shared library and only under Linux?

Comment: Why do you still qmake when even Qt itself dropped it?

Comment: The project started using Qt in 2014 and qmake was pretty common back then. There are no resources (time) at the moment to make a transition. I barely manage to work on features that are much more important than build tool migration.

Comment: It should be very easy to port and the fact that you do not get support for this is due to using a dead and unmaintained technology. You will spend time more time on qmake than your actual work.

Comment: First of all I would need to learn CMAKE - I have never used it, even a little. Secondly - in some plugins (which have their own `pro` files) I did some hacks, which might not be as easy to port as it seems to. Nevertheless, I still think a lot of projects still use qmake and a lot of people know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

#### Short answer

Add `QMAKE_RESOURCE_FLAGS += -name coreSQLiteStudio_qm_files` to all `pro` files (and replace the `coreSQLiteStudio_qm_files` to unique name in each case).

If you have other (explicit) resource files in the project, you will need to have dynamic, but predictible names, like: `QMAKE_RESOURCE_FLAGS += -name ${QMAKE_TARGET}_${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}`, so you can pass it to the `Q_INIT_RESOURCE()` macro.

#### Long answer

The auto-generated (by qmake) resource file with qm files inside is compiled by the `rcc` into cpp file with a default initialization function `qInitResources_qmake_qmake_qm_files()`, which then is repeated over all other modules (shared libraries) and causes only one of those to be used in the runtime. Solution is to make initialization functions unique for each module, therefore you need to pass unique name of the resource initialization function to the `rcc`. By using statement like above (in the short answer) you will get initialization function `qInitResources_coreSQLiteStudio_qm_files()`.

It seems like conflicting name of the function doesn't matter under Windows, but it does under Linux.